# How to download file in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am referring this https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#download-to-storage-directly I have converted JSON response which I received from API endpoint now I want to convert it into CSV file and download it how can I do that ?
When user clicks on download icon user must be able to download that JSON response as CSV  file.

To convert JSON response into CSV format I have used following code to separate out each field. (Also see screenshot)

code:

```
convertToCSV = (stm_leadsitevisits, projectName) => {
        // console.log("convert CSV Inside sitevisits: ",stm_leadsitevisits);

        let obj = [['Sr no','Name', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Project', 'Visited at', 'Attended by', 'Source', 'Feedback']];
        let data = stm_leadsitevisits;
        let csvRow = [];

        for(let item = 0; item<data.length; item++){
            obj.push([item, data[item].name, data[item].phone, data[item].email, projectName, data[item].created_time, 
                data[item].user.name, data[item].source, data[item].feedback ])
        }

        console.log("New data: ", obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the library uses the file as a cache and not as a persistant storage. I once used two libraries to read json files from disk and I guess the reverse (as is your case) could help you work this out, too.

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

https://github.com/luisfuertes/react-native-file-picker

Here is the code I used to open a file with RNFS and RNFP, just to give you a starting point.

```
pickFile = () => {
    // (1) Browse for file
    DocumentPicker.show({
        filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.allFiles()],
    }, (error, file) => {
        // (2) Copy file to accessible path
        let destPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + file.fileName;
        RNFS.copyFile(file.uri, destPath)
            .then((success) => {
                console.log('file copied!');
                // (3) Read file content and parse to JSON
                RNFS.readFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + file.fileName, 'utf8')
                    .then((contents) => {
                        let json = JSON.parse(contents);
                        // (4) dispatch reducer
                        this.props.addJsonFile(json);
                        ToastAndroid.show('Imported ' + file.fileName, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log('Error reading file: ' + err.message);
                    });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error copying file: ' + err.message);
            });

    });
};
```

And this is code from RNFS github page to write to a file:

```
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';

// write the file
RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Just found this section in the github you referred to:

```
let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
RNFetchBlob
.config({
  // response data will be saved to this path if it has access right.
  path : dirs.DocumentDir + '/path-to-file.anything'
})
.fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
  //some headers ..
})
.then((res) => {
  // the path should be dirs.DocumentDir + 'path-to-file.anything'
  console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
})
```

I guess it doesn't solve your problem, as the saving happens when the promise resolves and you need to convert the JSON to CSV *before* saving it. In that case, I would suggest to use RNFS or add a feature request to RN-fetch-blob to support this.

Cheers

Comment: I am referring this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTsgvzsgtek check 11th min to 11:30 min code I am doing similar thing but in react native not in reactjs. So I have converted the data in required format but now how can I download it in react native ? In reactjs in that video they have directly used ` a.download()`

Comment: can you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454900/how-to-write-and-download-file-in-react-native